# Python Text adventure Selling, check if its in list

Tags: python

I'm Coding a Text adventure game. First I coded my inventory

```
player_inventory = []
```

Since there should be nothing to begin with. and in the shop, when I buy something it would say

```
player_inventory.append(What Ever The Item Is Called)
```

And after that, if I print my inventory it would say

```
(player_name)s inventory :
.....
...
```

So now I want to add a selling system.
I tried stuff such as

```
def sell(player_inventory):
    print('selling:')
    for stuff in player_inventory:
        print(stuff)
    sold = input('what do you want to sell?')
    if (sold in player_inventory):
        print('successfully sold!!')
        player_inventory.remove(sold)
    return player_inventory
```

and then in the main game loop I would say

```
player_inventory = sell(player_inventory)
```

But when I sell something from my inventory It should say 'sucessfully sold!' and remove the item from my inventory, however Its not doing what I thought it would do.

From a example I did, I had a 'wooden_sword' in my inventory which I just did wood_sword = 'wooden_sword' at the beginning of the code. and I ran the sell function and typed 'wooden_sword' in but it wouldn't work. I kind of know the reason why but I can't solve it

I think that the reason is because

```
sold = input('what do you want to sell?')
```

is a different thing from my items. so even if I typed 'wooden_sword' since I did

```
wood_sword = 'wooden_sword'
```

it wouldnt work. I have to check if sold is equal to wood_sword instead of doing that but If I did that I would have too many lines on the function, anyone can help? ty for reading this

Comment: I wanted to put the full code in there but I exeeded the maximum characters by 4000 -_-

Comment: If the list contains `'wooden_sword'`, and the user types that exact string as input, then this should work.

Comment: you might take user input issues out and give them a numbered list of items in inventory and then they just put in the number.  Instead of wooden_sword, they put in 3 and you say "Confirm you want to sell your wooden_sword" ... then you can delete by index #, which might be handy if they can collect multiple of the same item name! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change the interface design from typing the item's name to a numbered list.  The user can select the number of the item to sell.  Here is an example function.

```
def sell(player_inventory):
    print('Available to sell::')
    for i, stuff in enumerate(player_inventory, 1):
        print(i, stuff)
    sold = input('what item number do you want to sell? ("q" to exit)')

    if sold == 'q':
        return player_inventory

    try:
        sold = int(sold)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please use the item number')
        return player_inventory

    if sold <= len(player_inventory):
        print('successfully sold!!')
        player_inventory.pop(sold - 1)
    return player_inventory
```