# Text Adeventure python sell system

Tags: python

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5003756/james for answering my previous post [Python Text adventure Selling, check if its in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66464653/python-text-adventure-selling-check-if-its-in-list/66464919#66464919) with

```
def sell(player_inventory):
    print('Available to sell::')
    for i, stuff in enumerate(player_inventory, 1):
        print(i, stuff)
    sold = input('what item number do you want to sell? ("q" to exit)')

    if sold == 'q':
        return player_inventory

    try:
        sold = int(sold)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please use the item number')
        return player_inventory

    if sold <= len(player_inventory):
        print('successfully sold!!')
        player_inventory.pop(sold - 1)
    return player_inventory
```

So anyways, thanks to James we now have a `sell` function which runs perfectly fine. But the thing is, I want to make it so the way the money gets added to my

```
player_money
```

How I could add `money` in there? When I run the `sell` function, it does take the item away from my inventory, but doesn't add money to

```
player_money
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if sold <= len(player_inventory):
        print('successfully sold!!')
        player_inventory.pop(sold - 1)
        player_money(add + amount)
    return player_inventory
```

you have to add a function where the items amount sold is stored and then that amount would be added to the function of the money in the players inventory.